# How to set a fixed size for a shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a circle of 4mm with minus sign inside it. I have set the `m` style:

```
\tikzstyle{m}=[circle, thin, draw=red, fill=red, minimum size=4mm]
```

however the minus sign extends the circle. I want the sign to almost fill the circle. I tried to change the line to be:

```
\tikzstyle{m}=[circle, thin, draw=red, fill=red, size=4mm]
```

but it didn't work.

How can I set the circle size to be fixed?

Comment: I usually just keep the circle empty, and add another node, at the same coordinate, that holds the text.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TikZ automatically adds separation between the text and the node border. When setting a minimum size for a node, it's usually a good idea to set `inner sep=0pt`:

```
\tikzstyle{m}=[circle, thin, draw=red, fill=red, minimum size=4mm,inner sep=0pt]
```