# Ellipse, circle, rectangle and rounded rectangle aligned by centering

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I create these aligned images intelligently and with millimeter dimensions?

[image]

I used GeoGebra to generate the code shown below.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0mm,0mm) ellipse (50mm and 20mm);

    \draw (150mm,0mm) circle (20mm);

    \draw (-50mm,-72.5mm)-- (50mm,-72.5mm);
    \draw (-50mm,-107.50mm)-- (50mm,-107.50mm);
    \draw (-50mm,-72.5mm)-- (-50mm,-107.50mm);
    \draw (50mm,-107.50mm)-- (50mm,-72.5mm);

    \draw (110mm,-72.5mm)-- (190mm,-72.5mm);
    \draw (110mm,-107.50mm)-- (190mm,-107.50mm);
    \draw (110mm,-72.5mm)-- (110mm,-107.50mm);
    \draw (190mm,-107.50mm)-- (190mm,-72.5mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to improve the code by defining the positions of the geometries using the centers as reference. Having the center of the ellipse in position `(0,0)`.

Dimensions do not have to be displayed. They are just for setting profile sizes.

The link in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7BEOJwRSlw&feature=youtu.be) demonstrates what I'm trying to learn. I'm Brazilian and so it's in Portuguese.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21163 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215811 -- basically use `minimum width` or `minimum height` and so on.

Comment: I would recommend to read the tikz documentation. It's full of examples.

Comment: I was studying this [video](https://youtu.be/C7BEOJwRSlw)

Comment: See this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14901 and the package `tikz-dimline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `positioning` to set the ceneter points, and then `calc` to draw the shapes. I have scaled it to half size to get a better fit on a normal page size, but you can get the true size by setting `x=1mm,y=1mm`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5mm,y=0.5mm]% Set the scale (default x and y is 1cm)
    \coordinate (a11);
    \coordinate[right=150 of a11](a12);
    \coordinate[below=90 of a11](a21);
    \coordinate[right=150 of a21](a22);
    %% 
    \draw[ultra thick] (a11) circle (50 and 20);
    \draw[dash dot] ($(a11)-(50+10,0)$) -- +($2*(50+10,0)$);
    \draw[dash dot] ($(a11)-(0,20+10)$) -- +($2*(0,20+10)$);
    %% 
    \draw[ultra thick] (a12) circle (20);
    \draw[dash dot] ($(a12)-(20+10,0)$) -- +($2*(20+10,0)$);
    \draw[dash dot] ($(a12)-(0,20+10)$) -- +($2*(0,20+10)$);
    %% 
    \draw[ultra thick] ($(a21)-(50,17.5)$) rectangle +(50*2,17.5*2);
    \draw[dash dot] ($(a21)-(50+10,0)$) -- +($2*(50+10,0)$);
    \draw[dash dot] ($(a21)-(0,17.5+10)$) -- +($2*(0,17.5+10)$);
    %%
    \draw[ultra thick,rounded corners=8] ($(a22)-(50,17.5)$) rectangle +(50*2,17.5*2);
    \draw[dash dot] ($(a22)-(50+10,0)$) -- +($2*(50+10,0)$);
    \draw[dash dot] ($(a22)-(0,17.5+10)$) -- +($2*(0,17.5+10)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: j]

Answer (score 4):

> Here's a start.

- There is a lot of unnecessary stuff (for a MWE) in your example (`\pagestyle{empty}` and the strange color definitions and -5.428299960530308 for example).
- Did you generate the code with another software?
- I removed everything and use `article` as the "better" MWE document class for most cases.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=30mm]
\node[circle,draw,minimum width = 20mm,anchor=center] (n1) {Circle};
\node[ellipse,draw,minimum width = 20mm,minimum height = 10mm,anchor=center,below=20mm of n1] (n2) {Ellipse};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width = 20mm,minimum height = 10mm,anchor=center,right=20mm of n2] (n3) {Rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe add this information to your question. You claim to have generated a minimal example which I strongly disagree.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I did not even know how to start. To have at least one minimal example, I had to do against it.

Comment: Still, just tell that the people here in your question: "I used GeoGebra to generate the code shown below." This is independent of if you are a beginner or not. I tried to understand the code first which was a waste of time.

Comment: I only ask to mention that you used GeoGebra to generate the code. Nothing else.